# Нужна устойчивая сортировка на C#

Tags: c#, сортировка

Как мне создать тоже самое в C# в консоли? Мне нужен объект такого же типа - таблица, как в примере ниже и такая же сортировка - устойчивая:

**Пример (описание) с [Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0):**

> При сортировке записей вида [фамилия, имя, отчество] по фамилии значения ключей для Иванов Сергей и Иванов Иван будут одинаковы, поэтому устойчивая сортировка не переставит Сергея и Ивана местами (Python 3, сортировка timsort[1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)):
>
> ```
> records = [
>    {'фамилия': 'Иванов',  'имя': 'Сергей', 'отчество': 'Михайлович',},
>    {'фамилия': 'Иванов',  'имя': 'Иван',   'отчество': 'Борисович',},
>    {'фамилия': 'Абрамов', 'имя': 'Юрий',   'отчество': 'Петрович',},
> ]
> records.sort(key=lambda x: x['фамилия'])  # сортировка по ключу "фамилия"
> for r in records:
>     print('%-12s %-12s %-12s' % (r['фамилия'], r['имя'], r['отчество'])
> ```
>
> В результате записи будут отсортированы только по фамилии, с
>   сохранением исходного порядка среди записей с одинаковыми фамилиями:
>
> ```
> Абрамов Юрий Петрович 
> Иванов Сергей Михайлович 
> Иванов Иван Борисович
> ```

Comment: LINQ`овский [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx#Anchor_2) выполняет stable sort.

Comment: а могу я так строки двумерного list устойчиво отсортировать по возрастанию первого столбца?

C#
    List<List<int>> tbl = new List<List<int>>();
                tbl = {
                    { 3,8,5},
                    { 5,7,4},
                   { 4,9,5}
                   { 1,9,4}, };

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Почему не как ответ?

Answer (score 2):

На C# это будет выглядеть так:

```
var sorted = records.OrderBy(x => x.Surname);
foreach (var r in records)
    Console.WriteLine($"{r.Surname,-12} {r.Name,-12} {r.Patronymic,-12}");
```

---

Ответ [дан в комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/730377/730395#comment1107882_730377) @Alexander Petrov