# Устойчивая сортировка строк двумерного list по возрастанию первого столбца - C#

Tags: c#

Нужна устойчивая сортировка строк двумерного list  по возрастанию первого столбца

```
List<List<int>> tbl = new List<List<int>>();
```

На входе:

```
         tbl ={
              { 3,8,5},
              { 5,7,4},
              { 4,9,5}
              { 1,9,4}, }
```

На выходе:

```
        tbl ={
             { 1,9,4},
             { 3,8,5},
             { 4,9,5}
             { 5,7,4}, }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730377

Comment: Помогите как в примере выход получить, не пойму как применительно для list это сделать, как на него ссылаться, не хочу пользоваться var и сразу выводить

Comment: Нужна именно сортировка строк - по возрастанию элементов 1-ого столбца

Comment: Сортировать нужно точно так же, через OrderBy. А вывести массив на консоль, думаю, вы и сами сможете.

Comment: Вывести смогу, помогите VladD сделать сортировку через OrderBy, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

По ответу @VladD и комментарию @AlexanderPetrov из [Нужна устойчивая сортировка на C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/730377)

```
List<List<int>> tbl = new List<List<int>>()
{
    new List<int>()  { 3,8,5},
    new List<int>()  { 5,7,4},
    new List<int>()  { 4,9,5},
    new List<int>()  { 1,9,4}
};
var sorted = tbl.OrderBy(x => x[0]);
// или
List<List<int>> sorted = tbl.OrderBy(x => x[0]).ToList();
```

Comment: Igor, а как эту сортировку поменять, на поубыванию?

Comment: @СергейБекмамбетов `tbl.OrderBy(x => x[0]).Reverse()...`, или `tbl.OrderBy(x => -x[0])` :)

Comment: `OrderByDescending` же.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример.

```
        List<List<int>> tbl = new List<List<int>>()
        {
            new List<int>() { 3,5,4,1},
            new List<int>() { 8,7,9,9},
            new List<int>() { 5,4,5,4}
        };
```

вот в консоли.

```
   List<IOrderedEnumerable<int>> Result = tbl.Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => 
                                                               y)).ToList();

        foreach (var item in Result)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in item)
            {
                Console.Write(item2);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: Подождите, что все-таки мы хотим отсортировать?

Comment: Я тоже сортирую @Igor примените мой пример.

Comment: Пример хорош, спору нет :). Повторю вопрос: что имеется в виду отсортировать?